# Сериализация коллекции в Java

Tags: java

Можно ли проводить сериализацию не объекта класса, а коллекции?

Есть код, где пытаюсь провести сериализацию `List`, но значения листа не сохраняются в файл добавленный в пакет проекта, так же не проходит десериализация, на методе `readObject` выпадает ошибка?

```java
public void serialize(List > String < exitData) {
  try {

    FileOutputStream a = new FileOutputStream("DataExit.json");
    ObjectOutputStream b = new ObjectOutputStream(a);
    b.writeObject(exitData);
    b.flush();
    b.close();
    a.close();
  } catch (IOException i) {
    i.printStackTrace();
  }
}

public void deSerialize() {
  try {

    FileOutputStream a = new FileOutputStream("DataExit.json");
    ObjectOutputStream b = new ObjectOutputStream(a);
    exitDeserial = (ArrayList) b.readObject(); //?????
    b.close();
    a.close();
  } catch (IOException i) {
    i.printStackTrace();
    return;
  } catch (ClassNotFoundException j) {
    System.out.println("List not found");
    j.printStackTrace();
    return;
  }
  for (String t: exitDeserial) {
    System.out.println(t);
  }
}
```

Comment: выложите, пожалуйста, класс объекта который пытаетесь сериализовать

Comment: В том то и дело, что сериализовать пытаюсь не обобьет класса, а коллекцию.

Comment: По какой причине не хотите сериализовать весь объект?

Comment: В классе вычисляются значения, что бы их сериализовать необходимо создавать еще один класс, решил, что можно попробовать сохранить их в лист и потом его сериализовать.

Comment: Вот что нашел на просторах интернета "ArrayList сериализуется по умолчанию. Это означает, что вам не нужно явно реализовывать сериализуемый интерфейс, чтобы сериализовать ArrayList."

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Можно сделать так:

```
String path = "D:\\list.obj";
List<Integer> list;        
if (!new File(path).exists()) {
    list = List.of(1, 2, 3, 4, 5);
    try (final ObjectOutputStream ObjectOutputStream = new ObjectOutputStream(new FileOutputStream(path))) {
        ObjectOutputStream.writeObject(list);
    }
} else {
    try (final FileInputStream FileOutputStream = new FileInputStream(path); 
         final ObjectInputStream ObjectInputStream = new ObjectInputStream(FileOutputStream)) {
        list = (List) ObjectInputStream.readObject();
    }
    System.out.println(list);
}
```

Вывод:

```
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
```

Сразу вы не увидите вывода, так-как сначала будет запись объекта, а после уже когда файл существует, добавится в коллекцию.

Или вообще сделать отдельно класс для этого:

```
public final class Serialize {

    private final String path;
    private final File file;
    private Object object;

    public Serialize(final String path) {
        this.path = path;
        this.file = new File(path);
    }

    public void serialize(final Object object) {
        try (final FileOutputStream FileOutputStream = new FileOutputStream(path);
             final ObjectOutputStream ObjectOutputStream = new ObjectOutputStream(FileOutputStream)) {
            ObjectOutputStream.writeObject(object);
        } catch (final IOException io) {
            //...логи ошибок
        }
    }

    public Object deserialize() {
        try (final FileInputStream FileOutputStream = new FileInputStream(path);
             final ObjectInputStream ObjectInputStream = new ObjectInputStream(FileOutputStream)) {
            object = ObjectInputStream.readObject();
        } catch (final IOException | ClassNotFoundException ex) {
            //...логи ошибок
        }
        return object;
    }

    public boolean is() {
        return null != this.file && this.file.exists();
    }
}
```

И уже использовать так:

```
final Serialize ser1 = new Serialize("D:\\list.obj"),
                ser2 = new Serialize("D:\\str.str");
if (!ser1.is()) {
    ser1.serialize(List.of(1, 2, 3, 4, 5));
}
List<Integer> list = (List<Integer>) ser1.deserialize();
System.out.println(list); // [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]

if (!ser2.is()) {
    ser2.serialize("String"); 
}
String string = (String) ser2.deserialize();
System.out.println(string); // String
```

Мможно сделать сразу динамическое приведения к нужному типу, во время вызова `deserialize`.

```
public <T> T deserialize() {
    try (final FileInputStream FileOutputStream = new FileInputStream(path);
        final ObjectInputStream ObjectInputStream = new ObjectInputStream(FileOutputStream)) {
        final Object Object = ObjectInputStream.readObject();
        final Class<?> Class = Object.getClass();
        return (T) Class.cast(Object);
    } catch (final IOException | ClassNotFoundException ex) {
        //...логи ошибок
        return null;
    }
}
```

И можно уже будет использовать так:

```
final Serialize ser1 = new Serialize("D:\\list.obj"),
                ser2 = new Serialize("D:\\str.str");
if (!ser1.is()) {
    ser1.serialize(List.of(1, 2, 3, 4, 5));
}
List<Integer> list = ser1.deserialize();
System.out.println(list); // [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]

if (!ser2.is()) {
    ser2.serialize("String"); 
}
String string = ser2.deserialize();
System.out.println(string); // String
```

Вывод аналогичный с вариантом выше.

Answer (score 2):

Вы должны сериализовать объект. Да он может содержать в себе коллекции других сериализуемых объектов.

Все Ваши объекты должены реализовывать интерфейс `Serializable`, и содержать в себе константу `serialVersionUID` - уникальный идентификатор версии сериализованного класса. Чтоб объект мог быть десериализован, текущее значение в классе и в сериализованном объекте должны совпадать.

Схема такая:

```
public class Person implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    ...

    private List<Document> documents; 

    private transient String secret; //данное поле не будет сериализовано
}


public class Document implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    ...


}
```

подробно можете посмотреть здесь https://javarush.ru/groups/posts/2022-serializacija-i-deserializacija-v-java

Comment: `serialVersionUID` указывать полезно, но не обязательно.

Comment: @SergeyGornostaev Обязательно, если вы его не укажите, при любом изменении класса, при компиляции его значение вычислится автоматически. Что будет автоматически означать что старые объекты  вы не сможете десериализовать

Comment: Обязательно - это когда без указания сериализация вообще не происходит. А описанный вами сценарий - это "полезно" или "необходимо при использовании с разными версиями JVM".

Answer (score 0):

можно использовать обертку для сериализации/десериализации

```
  import com.fasterxml.jackson.core.JsonProcessingException;
    import com.fasterxml.jackson.core.type.TypeReference;
    import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper;
    
    import java.io.IOException;
    import java.util.ArrayList;
    import java.util.List;
    
    public class test {
    
        public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
            ArrayList<SUser> objects = new ArrayList<SUser>(){{
                add(new SUser("s1", "s2"));
                add(new SUser("s1", "s2"));
            }};
            byte[] bytes = new ObjectMapper().writeValueAsBytes(objects);
            ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();
            List<SUser> sUsers = objectMapper.readValue(bytes, new TypeReference<List<SUser>>() {
            });
            for (SUser sUser : sUsers) {
                System.out.println(sUser.getField1() + "   " + sUser.getField2());
            }
        }
}

////////////////////////////////////////
import java.io.Serializable;

public class SUser implements Serializable {
    private String field1;
    private String field2;

    public SUser() {
    }

    public SUser(String field1, String field2) {
        this.field1 = field1;
        this.field2 = field2;
    }

    public String getField1() {
        return field1;
    }

    public String getField2() {
        return field2;
    }

}

///////////////////////////////////////////////
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-databind</artifactId>
            <version>2.12.1</version> //check for new version
        </dependency>
```